# Net.Socket instances don't go away in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to recreate the functionality of a hardware serial server with Node and it's actually working, but I'm getting errors from socket instances that have been closed.

Here's a simplified version of the app to show what I'm doing...

```
var net = require('net');
var SerialPort = require('serialport');
var connectionCounter = 0;
var port = new SerialPort('/dev/ttyUSB0', function () {
    var server = net.createServer();
    server.on('connection',function(socket) {
      connectionCounter++;
      var connNumber = connectionCounter;
      socket.on('error', function () {
        console.log('socket ' + connNumber + ' errored');
      });
      socket.on('data', function(data) {
        port.write(data);
      });
      port.on('data', function(data) {
        socket.write(data);
      });
    });
    server.listen(8887, '127.0.0.1');
  }
});
```

So the first chunk of code that's sent into the 8887 port works fine, and it returns the data back out through the socket. The errors start on the second chunk. In the example, I'm keeping a count of the socket instances and outputting the socket instance number with the error. So as the program runs, the number of sockets instances keeps going up. The most recent instance will eventually handle the data, but I can't figure out what I need to delete to clean up all of the previous socket instances so they'll stop trying to process the incoming data.

I've tried socket.end() and socket.destroy(), but those don't seem to work . Do I need to go as far as deleting the server itself and recreating it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone ever finds this and cares about what was going wrong, I was setting an event listener on the serialport object every time a new net socket was created. So even though I was deleting the socket every time it was closed, the serialport listener was trying to send data to all of the old deleted sockets. So the solution was to removeListeners from the serialport object upon closing the net socket.

Answer (score 0):

you can use array for storing sockets later on you can delete. this is sample code hope you got the idea

```
var net = require('net');
var SerialPort = require('serialport');
var connectionCounter = 0;
var mySockets = [];
var port = new SerialPort('/dev/ttyUSB0', function () {
    var server = net.createServer();
    server.on('connection',function(socket) {
    mySockets.push(socket);
      connectionCounter++;
      var connNumber = connectionCounter;
      socket.on('error', function () {
        console.log('socket ' + connNumber + ' errored');
      });
      socket.on('data', function(data) {
        port.write(data);
      });
      port.on('data', function(data) {
        socket.write(data);
      });
    });
    server.listen(8887, '127.0.0.1');
  }
//get the sockets you want to delete
var s = mySockets.pop();
s = null;
});
```

Comment: Setting the socket to null or undefined or even using delete on it isn't working. Somehow it's still listening to that port and throwing an error message. Am I trying to delete the wrong thing?

Comment: You are right about keeping track of the sockets, but it turns out I was putting a listener on the serial port that was causing the error. Thanks for taking time to help.